# set value of element of an object jquery

Tags: jquery, object

I have an object in Jquery and I want to set the  element page to 100 for example, how can I do that with jquery?

```
 var options = {
      valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
      page: 3,
      plugins: [
          [ 'paging' ]
      ]
    };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery required as that is a POJS object. Assuming you mean that you want to change the `page` property after the object is created this will work:

```
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
    page: 3,
    plugins: [
        [ 'paging' ]
    ]
};

options.page = 100;
```

Comment: thanks but what about when a user clicks an <a> for an example, I want it to be set

Comment: Assuming `options` has global scope, put the above line of code in a click handler: `$('#foo').click(function() { options.page = 100; });`. For future reference, you should add all details about your question at the start. It would have been helpful to know how you wanted the code to be executed.

Comment: sorry my bad, it doesn't seem to have global scope because that doesn't work, is there a way to do so considering this?

Comment: Not really. The click event handler cannot be passed a parameter, so either `options` needs to have global scope (ie. declared outside the click handler) or be declared inside the click handler (which would render changing the page value pointless);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to change the option property value.

```
options.page = 100;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6PNb/

Comment: thanks but what about when a user clicks an <a> for an example, I want it to be set